# Is it necessary to update from xe4 to xe6 for desktop applciation

Tags: delphi

I develop desktop application I don't need to develop mobile application because its large size in Delphi Is it necessary to update xe4 to xe6 , I mean is xe4 is same for desktop application like xe6 
thank you fro help

Comment: XE6 has compiler, RTL, and VCL changes. It's only necessary to upgrade if any of those changes would benefit you. We don't have your code or know anything about your app, so we can't offer advice about that; you can read the list of what's new in XE5 and XE6 in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/What%27s_New) and decide that for yourself.

Comment: According to some folks, Delphi 7 was the last "real" Delphi platform for building Desktop apps with. ;-)

Comment: Why do you think it might be necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Delphi XE4 and XE6 are basically the same when it comes to developing desktop, VCL based applications.

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific. What does "basically the same" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the edition, you'll get FireDAC, which is awesome. And there are pretty useful REST components.

Only you know if that makes updating a necessity for you :)

Comment: We got FireDAC yet with Delphi XE3.

Comment: @TLama: strange, i never received FireDAC with XE3 at the time. I thought it was first offered as an extra for XE4, and it was only bundled with XE5 for the first time

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean when FireDAC became part of Delphi. Well, that's true. Fortunately, if you bought XE3 Enterprise or above, you [`got it for free`](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29318) :-)